# Download file from primefaces tree

Tags: jsf, tree, download, primefaces

This is my `xhtml-code`

```
        <p:tree value="#{documentsController.root}"
                var="node" selectionMode="single"
                dynamic="true">

            <p:treeNode 
                expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open"
                collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
                <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
            </p:treeNode>

            <p:treeNode type="file" icon="ui-icon-document">
                <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
            </p:treeNode>

            <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{documentsController.onNodeSelect}"/>

        </p:tree>
```

and this is the backing bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DocumentsController implements Serializable {

    TreeNode root;
    //TreeNode[] selectedNodes;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        root = new DefaultTreeNode("SRC", null);

        TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("A", root);
        TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("B", root);
        TreeNode node2 = new DefaultTreeNode("C", root);

        TreeNode node3 = new DefaultTreeNode("file", "D", node0);
        TreeNode node4 = new DefaultTreeNode("file", "E", node0);
        TreeNode node5 = new DefaultTreeNode("file", "F", node0);

        String p = "C:\\Users\\federico.martinez\\Desktop\\a.wmv";

        TreeNode node6 = new DefaultTreeNode("file", new File(p), node1);
        TreeNode node7 = new DefaultTreeNode("file", "h", node1);
        TreeNode node8 = new DefaultTreeNode("file", "i", node1);

    }

    public TreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    /*
    public void setSelectedNodes(TreeNode[] selectedNodes){
    this.selectedNodes = selectedNodes;
    }

    public TreeNode[] getSelectedNodes(){
    return selectedNodes;
    }*/
    public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {
        if (event.getTreeNode().getType().equals("file")) {
            File file = new File(event.getTreeNode().getData().toString());
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();

            externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Type", externalContext.getMimeType(file.getName()));
            externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
            externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");

            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;

            try {
                input = new FileInputStream(file);
                output = externalContext.getResponseOutputStream();
                IOUtils.copy(input, output);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("FileNotFound: " + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("IO: " + ex.getMessage());
            } finally {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
            }
            facesContext.responseComplete();
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not downloading the file, I used this download method with the Tomahawk tree and it worked, now I'm trying with PrimeFaces but this doesn't download the file and no error!

any advise what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance !

**UPDATE**

I have this modification but can't make it download the file.

```
        <p:tree value="#{documentsController.root}"
                var="node" selectionMode="single"
                dynamic="true">

            <p:treeNode 
                expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open"
                collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
                <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
            </p:treeNode>

            <p:treeNode type="file" icon="ui-icon-document">
                <p:commandButton value="#{node}" ajax="false">
                    <p:fileDownload value="#{documentsController.download(node)}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:treeNode>

        </p:tree>
```

and the backbean is

```
public void download(String path) {

    File f = new File(path);
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();

    InputStream is = ((ServletContext)externalContext.getContext()).getResourceAsStream(path);

    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(is, externalContext.getMimeType(f.getName()), f.getName());   

}

public StreamedContent getFile(){
    return file;
}
```

Comment: I don't have the time right now to test it--but odds are that its the AJAX call inside the primefaces API that's "eating" your request to download. What you should do look at is instead of using the actionlistener display a <p:fileDownload /> with 'ajax="false"' for the download file. This will create a link (it can be dynamically altered in advance) that will persist instead of triggering an update. I've had a similar problem with the table and this knocked it out quickly. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! the <p:fileDownload> replaces the ajax tag? or the treeNode tag (the one that displays the doc) ?

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that you're attempting to download a file by an Ajax request. This is not possible. Ajax is executed and managed by JavaScript code. JavaScript has due to security restrictions no facilities to trigger a *Save As* dialogue. You need to fire a fullworthy synchronous request instead. The original page will remain the same anyway if the content disposition is set to `attachment`.

So, you need at least a `<h:commandButton>` or `<p:commandButton ajax="false">`.

Your second problem which you got when you attempted to use `<p:fileDownload>` is that the `value` must point to a method returning `StreamedContent`, not `void`. You've bound it to a `void` method and hence nothing will be returned.

So, you need to return `StreamedContent` on `<p:fileDownload>` value.

Your third problem is that you're getting the file as classpath resource by `ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()` (which I believe you blindly copypasted from PrimeFaces showcase example, which in turn is by itself also pretty poor, it could just have used `ExternalContext#getResourceAsStream()` instead without the need to grab `ServletContext` from under the JSF's hoods, but that aside), instead of `FileInputStream` as in your original code.

So, either of those solutions must help:

```
<p:treeNode type="file" icon="ui-icon-document">
    <p:commandButton value="#{node}" ajax="false">
        <p:fileDownload value="#{documentsController.download(node)}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:treeNode>
```

with

```
public StreamedContent download(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    return new DefaultStreamedContent(input, externalContext.getMimeType(file.getName()), file.getName());   
}
```

*or*

```
<p:treeNode type="file" icon="ui-icon-document">
    <h:commandButton value="#{node}" action="#{documentsController.download(node)}" />
</p:treeNode>
```

with your original `onNodeSelect()` method with the argument changed to `String path`.

Comment: Puf... well I tried with yours (the same exact code) and some variations of mine but the only thing happening is the page refreshes (as if I was going to be redirected to somewhere else) and no file is downloaded ...

Comment: I've seen some odd problems with `<p:fileDownload>` before (I've by myself never used it before, so I can't go in detail). Try a regular `<h:commandButton>` instead.

Comment: Balus is dead on the money here: the behavior is "erratic" inside the components sometimes. You could try inverting it so instead of a method call you simply have a Collection<Item> and each element is a "downloadable" streamed content--its usually the approach I take and it works. Double check to make sure ajax="false"--it will break it.